# Filter an array of objects by the property inside an object contained in an array inside the object iterated [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

The structure of the objects inside the array to filter is the following:

```
videos:[
  {
    name: 'video name'
    url: 'video url'
    tags: [
      {
        tag: 'reels',
        // other tag info
      },
      {
        tag: 'demos',
        // other tag info
      },
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

i need to filter the videos array by the property tag on the objects inside the tags array, for example, i need to get an array with all the video objects on which tags array exist an object with the tag property 'reels'

**what i tried***

```
videos.filter(video => video.tags.tag === 'reels');
```

that returns an empty array because i'm not accessing the objects inside tags to read the tag property, so i tried the following

```
videos.filter(video => {
  video.tags.forEach(tag => {
    if (tag.tag === 'reels') {
      return true:
    };
  });
});
```

that looks kinda crazy and inconsistent, but i thought that i could iterate over the tags array inside each video being iterated on the videos.filter and return true, but it doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close to correct with the second try. If you change it from forEach to find and return the value, it will work.

```js
const videos = [
  {
    name: 'video name',
    url: 'video url',
    tags: [
      {
        tag: 'reels',
      },
      {
        tag: 'demos',
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'video name2',
    url: 'video url2',
    tags: [
      {
        tag: 'demos',
      },
    ]
  },
];

const filtered = videos.filter(video => {
  return video.tags.find(tag => {
    if (tag.tag === 'reels') {
      return true;
    };
  });
});

console.log(filtered);

// shortened to one line
const filtered2 = videos.filter(video => video.tags.find(tag => tag.tag === 'reels'));

console.log(filtered2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Several ways to accomplish the same thing, it's possible to do this with `.some` which "*tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.* "

```
videos.filter(video => video.tags.some(t => t.tag === "reels"));
```

Comment: It doesnt achieve the desired behavior, it just returns true if one element passes the test, it doesn't return an array with all the objects that passes the test

Comment: Sorry, I must be confused.  I thought you simply needed to get items, within the Video Array, whose tag equals 'reels' ?  I wrote a JSBin which uses both your selected answer and mine, but I don't see a difference? https://jsbin.com/qufeyusotu/edit?js,console

Comment: Oh, you are absolutely right, this is my bad, i made a mistake testing your answer, but it is correct too. I can't score it up unless you edit it.

Comment: Ah no harm, no foul. I've made a slight edit for you